# Android Notifications in the background

Tags: android, mobile

I am attempting to create an app that sends notifications to user while it is not the current app or open in the recent apps. I can create an application that sends notifications when the app is open, but cannot keep it going when the app is not the current app. I have attempted to use services but to no success. Any help is great.

I am testing my program on Samsung Galaxy A 50, running Android 9 Pie. I wish for my application to send notifications at a repeating time using AlarmManager. I am trying to use the service class to allow for notifications to be sent to the user while the app is closed

Comment: is it device specific?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60143405/edit) your post to include which OS versions & devices you are testing on. Including details on how your service works would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are receiving notifications while your app is in foreground but not in background or killed state.

Here is a quick suggestion, Instead of sending notification with **"notification"** keyword try to change this to **"data"**

```
Example:

{
   "to": "device token"
   "notification":{
    "title":"Title",
     "body":"Body"
   },
   "priority":123
 }

Change to this:

{
   "to": "device token"
   "data":{
     "title":"Title",
     "body":"Body"
   },
   "priority":123
 }
```

**onMessageReceived** is provided for most message types, with the following exceptions:

1. **Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background.** In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.
2. **Messages with both notification and data payload, when received in the background.** In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

[image]

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#sample-receive